# Excel VBA Copy operation inside loop is extremely slow

Tags: excel, performance, vba

The following sub has a Copy statement inside its loop that takes over 2 seconds to execute in Excel 2013. So that would be over 40 seconds for 20 iterations. I have tried all the usual optimations , like disabling events and screen updates. Does anyone have the same problem?

```
Sub TEST_SUB(surface)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A4:Z400").ClearContents


y = 4   'y is the row on sheet3 where we want to paste
For x = 4 To 20 'x is the current row from which we want to copy
        ' Decide if to copy based on whether the value in col 10 matches the parameter Surface
        ThisValue = Sheets("Tests_Master").Cells(x, 10).Value
        If ThisValue = surface Or x = 4 Then
            R1 = "A" + CStr(x) + ":K" + CStr(x) 'Range to copy from: row X columns 1-10

            'This next statement taks about 2 seconds to execute ! WHY????
            Sheets("Tests_Master").Range(R1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" + CStr(y))
            y = y + 1

        End If

Next x
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Copy/paste is slow. If you only need values, set ranges to each other or use array.

Comment: Actually, I have simplified the issue to this: Even with a brand new sheet1 opened in excel all by itself the following statement takes about 2 seconds to execute:        Sheets("sheet1").Range("A4").Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("B4")

Comment: Copy the sheet "Tests_Master" into an array then the do all the comparisons in there and take the values from there to copy them to "Sheet3". Accessing a worksheet is slowing down VBA. So you should limit  the times you are reading from a sheet or writing to it.

Comment: If ThisValue = surface Or x = 4 Then
                R1 = "A" + CStr(x) + ":K" + CStr(x)
                R2 = "A" + CStr(y) + ":K" + CStr(y)
                Sheets("sheet3").Range(R2) = Sheets("Tests_Master").Range(R1).Value
               
                y = y + 1
                
            End If

Comment: Looks like the following code change did the job:

Comment: If ThisValue = surface Or x = 4 Then
                R1 = "A" + CStr(x) + ":K" + CStr(x)
                R2 = "A" + CStr(y) + ":K" + CStr(y)
                Sheets("sheet3").Range(R2) = Sheets("Tests_Master").Range(R1).Value
               
                y = y + 1
                
            End If

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications, using the tip

> Optimize your code by explicitly reducing the number of times data is transferred between Excel and your code. Instead of looping through cells one at a time to get or set a value, get or set the values in the entire range of cells in one line, using a variant containing a two-dimensional array to store values as needed.

from this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx#xlFasterVBA) I modified your code:

```
Sub TEST_SUB(surface)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A4:Z400").ClearContents    

    y = 4   'y is the row on sheet3 where we want to paste
    For x = 4 To 20 'x is the current row from which we want to copy
    ' Decide if to copy based on whether the value in col 10 matches the parameter Surface
        ThisValue = Sheets("Tests_Master").Cells(x, 10).value
        If ThisValue = surface Or x = 4 Then
            R1 = "A" + CStr(x) + ":K" + CStr(x) 'Range to copy from: row X columns 1-10

            'Is faster use an array to store a range to copy after
            rangeToCopy = Sheets("Tests_Master").Range(R1)
            Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" + CStr(y) + ":K" + CStr(y)) = rangeToCopy

            'This next statement taks about 2 seconds to execute ! WHY????
            'Sheets("Tests_Master").Range(R1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A" + CStr(y))
            y = y + 1

        End If

    Next x

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

P.S.: Sorry my english

Comment: Can you explain your modifications and why they are an improvement over OP's original

Comment: Hi @litelite, I just use the recommendation of MSDN article [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff726673(v=office.14).aspx#xlArraySumProduct). It's better read and write a large block of data in a single operation.

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please quote the appropriate parts of the link you provided into the answer itself. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank's @litelite!